# How to give a number to array?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

For example i have an array with names:
      int n = numberofplayers();  //declaring number of players

```
  String[] myarray = new String[n];  //declaring array with players in game
  for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
  myarray[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Give me the names of players");
                       }
```

I dont know how to give specific number to each name,like:
1.Stefan
2.Oleg
3.Andrew

Comment: your number is i+1; and you would probably create it on the output, not the input.

Comment: Do you want to find a name given a number, or the other way around?

Comment: Your code is fine...what exactly is wrong?

Comment: The index of the array is your number for each name...

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
myarray[i] = (i + 1) + ". " + JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Give me the names of players");
```

It just prepends the loop variable `+ 1` and a `.` before the text entered in the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the in built indexing of the array as 'numbers' and then do this:

```
 for (int i=0;i<n.length;i++){
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
     System.out.print("Enter String");
     String s = br.readLine();
     n[0] = s;
 }
```

You have to make the array a string array. The first element in the array will be 0, second 1, etc. You can also make the first element blank so the actual players start from 1 or just add 1 to the index to get the logical player number.

Answer (score -1):

```
String[] myArray = new String[5];
for (int i=1; i<6; i++){
    myArray[i] = "Testname "+i;
}
```

This will make sure your array has 5 names with Testname 1 to Testname 5.

To show these names one could just print them:

```
System.out.println(myArray[1]);
```

which will output Testname 2